# Increment total replies to a post

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In my database, I have the following structure for posts:

```
post_id | reply_to | parent_id
   1         1           1
   2         1           1
   3         2           1
   4         3           1
```

So in this case, post_id 1 is the main post, while post_id 2 is a reply to post_id 1, post_id 3 is a reply to post_id 2, and post_id is a reply to post_id 3.

What I want to do is add another column that keeps track of the total number of replies to a post. So in the end, the table would look something like this:

```
post_id | reply_to | parent_id | total_replies
   1         1           1            3
   2         1           1            2
   3         2           1            1
   4         3           1            0
```

How/what would the query look like if I wanted to update the total number of replies?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just do a simple calculation per post, you do this:

```
UPDATE  posts 
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT post_id , (SELECT count(*) from posts p0 where p.post_id = p0.reply_to) as total_replies
            FROM posts p 
        ) p2 ON posts.post_id  = p2.post_id 
SET     posts.total_replies =p2.total_replies;
```

See it working there:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/868c6/1

Now, what you want is to do a **recursive** read, to calculate replies until it reach the top post. The worse way is to calculate this at quering data, so make it just when you save a new post, you can do this at PHP, or create a Store Procedure/Function in database, it'll be something like:

```
$total_reply = 0;

function calculateTotalReply($postId)
{

    //Make the simple sum as I did above
   $total_reply = $sum;

    //Check if is the top post
    if(!$isTheTopPost)
    {
         calculateTotalReply($parentPost);
    }

}
```

So, as you can see, it'll call himself until reach the top post, in the end at `$total_reply` you'll have your desired sum.

Comment: What is the `p` in `UPDATE posts p`?

Comment: @Bagwell it is an 'alias', because you'll have the same table name in UPDATE and SELECT, so we use it to differentiate. You can use any name.. I used 'p' because is the first letter, it's like a convention using the first letter from table to alias.

Comment: If I were to make a new reply to a post, I'm still not sure how I would update the total_replies. For example, in PHP, if I make a reply to a post, what would the query look like if I had the variables $post_id, $reply_to, and $parent_id?

Comment: @Bagwell I have updated my answer, now you have a link to see it working :) . When you add a new post, you just call this update again, and it'll update all posts, even the new one! For large projects , the best way is by Stored Procedures, you can learn this further..

Comment: Your updated answer isn't right. Here are the values that I used in my original post, and they're not outputting the total replies that I need: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e13e4/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e13e4/1)

Comment: @Bagwell, okay I see now. Check it again, I updated my answer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/868c6/1. But the total replies for "1" is 2, not 3 right? You only have 2 rows with reply_to = 1

Comment: No, it's what I said in the original post. This is because post id 2 is a reply to post id 1 (one), post id 3 is a reply to post id 2 which is a reply to post id 1 (two), and post id 4 is a reply to post id 3 which is a reply to post id 2 which is a reply to post id 1 (three). Total = 3. Same logic for the others.

Comment: @Bagwell Ok, now I fully understood. You need to do a **recursive** way. Like, while inside another while until you reach the top post. This is VERY bad to do at database for each query. The best way is when you save a new post. You can create this **recursive** loop to calculate what you want in PHP, or create a Stored Procedure in MySQL. You can't do this simple with just a couple of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
update posts p set total_replies = (select count(t.post_id) from 
posts t where t.reply_to = p.post_id)
```

Comment: What is the `p` in `UPDATE posts p`? What about the `t`?